# Representing relations in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to represent a relation (table) in C++ code:

- The columns of the relation are integers.
- The number of columns in the relation is fixed at runtime.
- No duplicates should be allowed (this is the major source of cost).
- I want to have a map from names to relations.

Any ideas for an efficient implementation, the main issue here is detecting duplicates at insertion time, it can be very costly.

Comment: Do you want names for the columns in a relation, or is an index Ok?

Comment: I prefer to have names, but I could do without them.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do with the relations you store? For instance, if your main goal is doing some aggregation stuff, other patterns might apply.

Comment: Why don't you use a ... database?

Comment: @ Space_C0wb0y: I just need to keep track of operations I performed to avoid redoing them: memoization.

@KennyTM: it is too expensive and the data is not large enough.

Answer (score 1):

Make each row of the table a `struct Row`.

Use a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` to store these structs. Collision (querying) can be detected in (for `std::set`) O(log n + d) time or (for `std::unordered_set`) amortized O(d) time where d is the number of columns.

To efficiently map from names to rows, create a [`boost::bimap<std::string, Row>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: But I do not know the schema of the row at compile time

Comment: @myahya: So use a `std::vector` for the rows.

Answer (score 0):

KennyTM has a point. You could use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html). As described in the link, you can use it to create a temporary in-memory database.

Comment: He made that comment earlier, I changed my post since then.